# Heroku: "No Python version was specified", but runtime.txt exists

Tags: python, heroku

I tried to deploy a python app to Heroku and I already have runtime.txt in the root of my directory but I don't know why Heroku can't find the "runtime.txt" file I specified and always gives this message:

```
Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.10.8
       To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.10.8
```

Project file structure:

[image]

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.7.15
```

I tried to find answers on Stack Overflow and find similar questions with no approved answers, but none wokred. I also tried to match my Python version with the Python runtime that is supported by Heroku.

Comment: python-3.7.15 is unsupported by stack 22. What happens if you change to stack 20 with `heroku stack:set heroku-20`?

Comment: Also, your VSCode suggests that you have not committed the `runtime.txt` file to git. Try to do that too.

Comment: @MichaelM. i have committed runtime file on last commit, ty

Comment: @MichaelM. changing my stack solve my problems, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you commit the `runtime.txt` file to git, otherwise, Heroku won't see it.

Also, Please see [the supported versions for each stack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes). Your message says that you're using Stack 22, but Python 3.7.15 is only supported by Stack 18 and Stack 20. This can easily be solved by changing your stack with `heroku stack:set heroku-20`.